# google api to get user city from IP

Tags: geolocation, ip-address

Currently I am using `ipinfo` api to get the city of users who come on my page. But it fails for many IPs and does not show city.

Is there any direct google API which gives city from user's IP?

I show google apis but it was giving city from langitude and lattitude. I dont have these values, I want to get direct city from IP.

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
    $citybyip= $details->city;
```